# Justified Gallery issue

Tags: html, css

I have small issue with Justified Gallery. I can't get rid of the spacing on the around the images, so the images are not properly aligned to the website grid.

It looks like there is a padding on the .photo-gallery wrapper but there is no padding. Check the red background on this page: http://dev.morris-chapman.com/wpdivi/news/nam-at-rhoncus-lacus/

I tried to apply negative margins on the container to make it fit the grid but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using this photo-gallery plugin: http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/options-and-events/

Then in your js file in `wp-content/themes/mc.init.js` there is this code:

```
$(".photo-gallery").justifiedGallery({
   rowHeight: 300,
   margins: 10,
});
```

I think if you set that margin to `0`, the problem disappears.

It's just an assumption because I can not test it.

### Edit 1

Maybe I understood your problem: it's border, not margin!

By default that plugin set border to -1:

> Decide the border size of the gallery. With a negative value the
>   border will be the same as the margins.

http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/options-and-events/

In the demo page the border is set to `0`, but if you don't set in your galley, it is the same of the margin: i.e `10px`.

So, to remove the problem, you can write this:

```
$(".photo-gallery").justifiedGallery({
   rowHeight: 300,
   margins: 10,
   border:0
});
```

Comment: Indeed that's the script I'm using. The strange thing is that on the page you mentioned, you can test params and whatever the value you set in the margin field, the images keeps properly aligned on the left/right. Anyway, I added a wrapper with negative margins and it works. But I would like to understand why this happen on my side and not on the example provided on http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/options-and-events/ :)

Comment: Thanks. Shame on me! how can I have miss this parameter! Anyway, thanks. Issue solved.